# Samsung np700z5b-s01ub getting the touch pad under control windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I'm attempting to use a samsung np700z5b-s01ub laptop with Windows 7 64-bit but the touch pad is practically unusable.  It's shear immense size causes it to be touched anytime I reach for it's keyboard.  I plugged in an external keyboard for this post simply because it's so difficult to type anything on this laptop.  I don't want to turn it off, but I really would love ot know why it works so badly and akwardly, is it multitouch?  Do I need to download some other drivers for it?

Comment: Touchpads on PCs made for Windows 7 are probably not multi-touch, because there wouldn't be much of a use for it. But to know for sure, you'll need to search through the specs. If you'd bought a "Windows 8 certified" PC or a Macbook, then I'd say it probably is. Now I don't quite understand your issue. Are you just saying you want to type without it being in the way? Then turn it off while typing, then turn it on while not typing, no?

Comment: After typing on it for a bit I've noticed that the issue has to do with the touch pad having two ways of clicking.  One has to do with simply lifting your finger up from the touch pad, and putting back down again resulting in a left click.  Applying additional force to the touch pad results in the entire touch pad area being pressed down.  There must be a way to turn one of these functionalities off, having them turned on together is a nightmare.

Comment: Ooooh, Mac style touchpads. Sounds like it is multi-touch, indeed. But to turn that option off, there is an option indeed. It's nothing complicated. I think it's on the control panel. I have neither Windows 7 or a laptop with me at the moment, but I remember turning it off on my mother's Windows 7 laptop. Probably in Mice and other pointing devices, or whatever that Control panel section is. Oh, and if you're not finding such an option, switch to classic view.

Comment: It's in the control panel as long as you have the driver installed.  I installed it and now I can actually type and click without having all sorts of weird things happen.  So I guess the short answer is go do a search for the drivers on the Samsung website for this machine, install the touch pad drivers for Win7 64 bit and then after you change the mouse settings in the last tab you'll be able to use the mouse as it was originally intended. :-p